# BMC Remedy ITSM search based on Last Resolved Date

Tags: remedy

I am trying to generate a report which should retrieve tickets that are resolved a working day before the current date. If I run the report on **14-OCt-2019 (Monday)**, then the results should fetch tickets resolved on **11-Oct-2019 (Friday)**

I tried this query but it is not generating the expected results `( 'Last Resolved Date' >= ( $TIMESTAMP$ - 2 * 24 * 24 * 60) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Last Resolved Date` sounds like a date field. You are using `$TIMESTAMP$`. Maybe you could consider using `$DATE$` instead?

Besides that, I don't quite get the maths:

One day would be `hours * minutes * seconds` (`24 * 60 * 60`) (I don't recall if `$TIMESTAMP$` uses milliseconds), nevertheless, this would give you the tickets in the last 24 hours, so If you check at 12:00 noon, you would only get part of the tickets.

I would use `'Last Resolved Date' >= ($DATE$ - ((60*60)*24))`

Answer (score 0):

if you have field for day of the week, add filter condition as your day of the week and try it.